# Creating views from star schema in data warehouse

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-warehouse

We have a lot of star schemas in our data warehouse. I thought I can create views in order to simplify SQL analysis of data.

Example SQL for profit&loss star:

```
select
    month_number,
    sum(amount)
from 
    bizdata.dw_daily_pl_fact dwdpf
    join bizdata.dw_distance dwdis on (dwdis.distance_key= dwdpf.distance_key)
    join bizdata.dw_ledger_account dwled on (dwled.ledger_account_key= dwdpf.ledger_account_key)
    join bizdata.dw_party dwpar on (dwpar.party_key= dwdpf.company_key)
    join bizdata.dw_party dwpar2 on (dwpar2.party_key= dwdpf.supplier_key)
    join bizdata.dw_budget_code dwbud on (dwbud.budget_code_key= dwdpf.budget_code_key)
    join bizdata.dw_time dwtim on (dwtim.time_key= dwdpf.time_key)
    join bizdata.dw_project dwpro on (dwpro.project_key= dwdpf.project_key)
where
    year_number = 2012
    and budget_code = 'SALARIES'
group by
    month_number
```

(There are approx 200 columns and 100k rows in this star)

If I have a view:

```
create or replace view bizdata.dwv_pl_fact as (
select
    *
from 
    bizdata.dw_daily_pl_fact dwdpf
    join bizdata.dw_distance dwdis on (dwdis.distance_key= dwdpf.distance_key)
    join bizdata.dw_ledger_account dwled on (dwled.ledger_account_key= dwdpf.ledger_account_key)
    join bizdata.dw_party dwpar on (dwpar.party_key= dwdpf.company_key)
    join bizdata.dw_party dwpar2 on (dwpar2.party_key= dwdpf.supplier_key)
    join bizdata.dw_budget_code dwbud on (dwbud.budget_code_key= dwdpf.budget_code_key)
    join bizdata.dw_time dwtim on (dwtim.time_key= dwdpf.time_key)
    join bizdata.dw_project dwpro on (dwpro.project_key= dwdpf.project_key)
);
```

I can simplify the statement to the following:

```
select
    month_number,
    sum(amount)
from 
    bizdata.dwv_pl_fact
where
    year_number = 2012
    and budget_code = 'SALARIES'
group by
    month_number
```

My questions is - Are there any performance or other issues with such approach?

Comment: Use EXPLAIN and EXPLAIN ANALYZE to see any differences. If there are any.

Comment: @FrankHeikens For this case, there are no differences. However I'm not sure this will be true in all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view in PostgreSQL is just a query rewriting mechanism. So you can basically assume your user-supplied criteria get merged into the view's definition and the resulting query gets run.

Since 9.0 it the planner should even notice some joins in the resulting query are unnecessary and skip them. That seems particularly useful in your case.

However, it is possible that some criteria may not be pushed "inside" clauses in the view definition - these would be the same as you might see with a sub-query though. For example,  a subquery with order-by + limit can present a boundary the planner can't see through.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned about the environment. In a generic model, your approach seems to be OK but you missed one great point. Keep in mind you are bringing all columns in that view. if there are 100s of column and there is a row chain, it will be nightmare. So rewrite the query and build the view(dwv_plk_fact) like following and you should be ok.

```
create or replace view bizdata.dwv_pl_fact as (
select
    <table_name>.month_number,
    <table_name>.amount
from 
    bizdata.dw_daily_pl_fact dwdpf
    join bizdata.dw_distance dwdis on (dwdis.distance_key= dwdpf.distance_key)
    join bizdata.dw_ledger_account dwled on (dwled.ledger_account_key= dwdpf.ledger_account_key)
    join bizdata.dw_party dwpar on (dwpar.party_key= dwdpf.company_key)
    join bizdata.dw_party dwpar2 on (dwpar2.party_key= dwdpf.supplier_key)
    join bizdata.dw_budget_code dwbud on (dwbud.budget_code_key= dwdpf.budget_code_key)
    join bizdata.dw_time dwtim on (dwtim.time_key= dwdpf.time_key)
    join bizdata.dw_project dwpro on (dwpro.project_key= dwdpf.project_key)
);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand what is your point. Can you  somehow improve your answer? We are on postgres (please note tags below my question)

Comment: It would be weird if this is needed in a star schema. Avoiding the * may be important in the queries (especially if PostgreSQL doesn't support table elimination), but not in the views.